# Prob $n$-th arrival of Poisson Process ($\lambda_{1}$) occurs before $m$-th arrival of P.P. ($\lambda_{2}$)?

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes

Define $ T_{1} $: time until $n$-th arrival of $ \{N_{1}(t)\} $;
$T_{2} $: time until $m$-th arrival of $ \{N_{2}(t)\} $.

$ \{N_{1}(t)\}, \{N_{2}(t)\} $ independent.

Then
\begin{align}
P(T_{1}<T_{2})&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} P(T_{1}<T_{2} \mid T_{2}{=}t)\cdot P(T_{2}{=}t)\: dt \\\\
&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=n}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda_{1}t}\frac{(\lambda_{1}t)^{j}}{j!} \cdot \lambda_{2}e^{-\lambda_{2}t}\frac{(\lambda_{2}t)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \: dt
\end{align}

*$ P(T_{1}<t) $ is the same as the prob. that there were at least $n$ events in $(0,t)$.

How do you simplify this? (Is this the right approach?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a combined process with rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.  Each arrival (independently) is from process $1$ with probability $ p = \lambda_1/(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$ and from process $2$ with probability $1-p$.  You want the probability that of the first $m+n-1$ arrivals, at least $n$ are from process
$1$.  That can be calculated using the binomial distribution.